Engineering Statics help

This was a question on one of my Statics homework. I am confused on how to start the process of solving. The homework is past due and I want to figure out the solution.

ask yourself ... does a vertical force on point A have any effect on the post?

With a true ball and socket joint, the moment will be 0 in all directions.

I'd look for symmetry and see if I could break it into a 2D problem for starters.  Solve that and then see how the to turn that 2D force into the required 3D forces

look at it in the yz plane and resolve the forces in each cable into vertical and horizontal parts.
